# Clicking Display All Running Tasks in the task manage yeilds Catastrophic Failure?

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

When I click `Display All Running Tasks` in Task Scheduler I get a dialog box that reads:

```
Catastrophic failure (Exceptiuon from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

Is there anything that can be done to remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this due to a corrupt task causing the snap-in to crash when navigating around.

If you was to browse to %windir% (windows directory normally c:\windows) then system32 and tasks, you can see all tasks created on a specific machine.

If you backup this folder and remove its content then try to load the task scheduler again hopefully this will resolve your issue. You can then copy the tasks back in one by one to try and locate the troublesome task.

Comment: How do I backup that folder?  When I do I get alot of "this folder already exists"?

Comment: You should normally just be able to copy and paste the contents to another folder elsewhere. Where are you trying to move them too?