# In an elevated Powershell prompt, why does Get-ScheduledTask always fail with "Catastrophic failure"?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, elevation

I want to use Powershell to enable and disable a Scheduled task, but `Get-ScheduledTask` task cannot access all the tasks that appear in the Task Scheduler GUI. I read on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240783/scheduled-tasks-dont-show-up-in-get-scheduledtask-result) that I should try running Powershell in an elevated prompt, but that completely fails. All use of `Get-ScheduledTask` in an elevated prompt results in the error `Get-ScheduledTask: Catastrophic failure` with no further info, even with the -Verbose option.

To reproduce:

1. Open an elevated Powershell 7 command prompt, for example by typing "Powershell 7" in the Windows search bar, and selecting the "Run as Administrator" menu option.
2. Type the command `Get-ScheduledTask`

The expected results are a list of all the scheduled tasks. My actual results are `Get-ScheduledTask: Catastrophic failure`

Why is this, and how can I access all my tasks?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with enough information to reproduce your issue?

Comment: There could be a corrupt task that you don't have access to in the UI without elevated privilges.  It's a pain, but try moving everything out of `%windir%\system32\tasks` and see if `get-scheduledtask` behaves.  If so, move them back in a bit at a time to try and narrow down the culprit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clicking Display All Running Tasks in the task manage yeilds Catastrophic Failure?](https://superuser.com/questions/898718/clicking-display-all-running-tasks-in-the-task-manage-yeilds-catastrophic-failur)

Comment: I tried removing all tasks from C:\Windows\System32\Tasks, that did not help. I was surprised to see that removing them had no effect on the tasks that were displayed in TaskScheduler. Perhaps the tasks are somewhere else? I Have Windows 10 64 Pro.